# Displaying Json object as a string instead of actual object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a function that populates a modal. I would like the modal to show the string from the data, not the JSON object or the JSON obj in string format. ... however it appears to be displaying the literal Json object...I cannot use a toString method because it appears it does not exist. Below is my code.

Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="receiptModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title">Receipt</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">   
           <div id="receiptTxt">

           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
  $(".viewReceipt").click(function (e) {

    var rowId = "#" + $(this).data("rowindex");
    var row = $(rowId);
    var transactionID = row.find(".transactionID").html().trim();

    var data = {
        receiptID: transactionID
    };

    console.log("data");
    console.log(data);

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("ViewReceipt", "TerminalReceipts")',
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("Success");
            console.log(data)
            $("#receiptTxt").html(data);
            $("#receiptModal").modal('toggle');
        }
    });
});
```

As you can see `$("#receiptTxt").html(data);` is the issue. It is literally displaying the data obj. I cannot do .html(data).toString().. what other options are there??

@edit

As requested, here is the output of `console.log(data)`

```
{"data":"                  Company Name                   \r\n          2222 Ridgelake Dr           \r\n              Cape Coral, FL, 90726               \r\n                                                \r\n                                                \r\n\r\n              10/4/2018 7:21:13 AM              \r\n\r\number: ABC123                        TID: ABC123\r\nBatch #:                                       0\r\nAccount #:                      XXXXXXXXXXXX2222\r\nTrans #:                                     378\r\nAuth #:                                 00056693\r\nHost Date:                             10/4/2018\r\nHost Time:                              09:24:50\r\nSoftware Version:                        1.0.0.0\r\n\r\n              THIS IS A DEMO                   \r\nTotal:                                    $5.00\r\n                    APPROVED                    \r\n\r\n              THANK YOU VERY MUCH!              \r\n\r\n"}
```

Comment: `JSON.stringify()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix like suck? `JSON.stringify($("#receiptTxt").html(data));`

Comment: `$("#receiptTxt").html(JSON.stringify(data));`  - you want to convert the data to a string, not the HTML elements.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix this is still displaying the actual JSON object just in string format

Comment: That is what you asked for `show the data in STRING format.`  if you want to add it to DOM elements, like `p` tags or what have you, then you will have to loop though the JSON data and do that with `.append()` etc...  There is no method to convert JSON to some arbitrary DOM structure.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix my apologies, I edited my OP.

Comment: Further if you want to build some kind of HTML structure from the JSON, your asking the impossible without providing a sample of the JSON and what it should look like when built.

Comment: Can you post what the output of `console.log(data)` is? `dataType: 'html'` implies `data` should be the string you want to display as-is. However, you state the issue is it shows a JSON object instead. The output will help us see if the string you want is actually a property of a JSON object.

Comment: @OXiGEN yes, I will edit the OP to show output of the log.

Comment: @OXiGEN done...

Comment: @Jacked_Nerd Comment out the `dataType: 'html'` setting so jQuery will try to auto-detect the data type. If that still doesn't work, leave it commented out and try `$("#receiptTxt").html(data.data);` in case your backend is using some odd wrapper to put the html you want into a `data` property for a JSON object.

Comment: @Jacked_Nerd Also just noticed you're using `data` as the variable name for the input as in `var data = {
        receiptID: transactionID
    };` and the output as in `success: function (data) {}`. To avoid potential scope conflicts, consider changing the output variable name to `response`.

Answer (score 2):

`JSON.stringify(data)`.

You can store this in a new variable or set it up this way: `$("#receiptTxt").html(JSON.stringify(data));`

You can use `JSON.parse()` to convert strings back to a JSON object.

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score -2):

This will give you a nicely formatted JSON string with indentation:

```
$("#receiptTxt").html(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
```

You will need to insert it into a `<pre>` element instead of a `<div>` to ensure new lines are correctly displayed.